# Register a device for Microsoft Autopilot in more than 1 tenant Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, intune

I try to register one device for Windows Autopilot in 2 different tenant Azure AD (It's like double registering the device). But it failed when I register on the 2nd Tenant (**error reason: Ztd device assigned to other tenant**), any explanation for this?

Comment: if you have any more query please let me know here in this comment.

Comment: If the answer helped you to figure out your problem you can mark it so that it would helpful to others

Comment: Ok, It explain a lot. Thx !

Comment: glad to hear, thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause**

This issue occurs if one of the following conditions is true:

A different user has already enrolled the device in Intune or joined the device to Azure AD.

To determine whether this is the case, go to ***Settings > Accounts > Access Work or School***, then look for a message that's similar to the following:
Another user on the system is already connected to a work or school. Please remove that work or school connection and try again.

The Configuration Manager client agent is installed on the computer.

**Resolution**

To fix this issue, use one of the following methods:

**Method 1:** Remove the other work or school account

To do this, follow these steps:
Sign out of Windows, then sign in by using the other account that has enrolled or joined the device.
Go to ***Settings > Accounts > Access Work or School***, then remove the work or school account.
Sign out of Windows, then sign in by using your account.
Enroll the device in Intune or join the device to Azure AD.

**Method 2:** Remove the Configuration Manager client, and then enroll the device again.

**Note:** Make sure you have register your app in correct way.

You can see here [autopilot profile assignment](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2018/06/13/autopilot-profile-assignment-using-intune/)

[Also Microsoft official document for Windows Autopilot here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-autopilot/windows-autopilot)